# Monkey command on android phone?

Tags: android, monkey

I'm ok using monkey command on the emulator but is it possible to launch it on a phone i'm using for debug?

Comment: nvm found the answer myself, i just need to launch the monkey using the -s option and passing the serial of the device (got it from the "adb devices" command) like that   -s serial shell

Comment: Post your comment as an answer and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just need to launch the monkey using the -s option and passing the serial of the device (got it from the "adb devices" command) like that -s serial shell

Comment: I started my app via the debugger in eclipse, logged it in, disabled the logout button and ran this command: caspar@caspars-macbook-pro~/Documents/android-sdk-mac_86/platform-tools: ./adb shell monkey -p com.soliant.android -v 5000